# Why does textview show different sizes between English and Chinese when attribute autoSizeTextType is uniform?

Tags: android, textview, autosize

As title,

Why does textview show different sizes between English and Chinese when attribute autoSizeTextType is "uniform"?
I print the width and height of textview, the value is the same.

The textview shows the same size between English and Chinese when the attribute autoSizeTextType is "uniform".

Comment: Do you mean, the sizes are different visually?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.